# Is there any way to add Date attribute in GEOADD method on redis serve

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Need Help in Following geoadd code

```
_ client.geoadd('drivers_locations', coordinates[0], coordinates[1], driverID ,new Date().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no time dimension available for [`GEOADD`](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd).

Depending on what you're doing, you might be able to emulate this by bucketing time into various keys, like

```
const key = `drivers_locations_${Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000 / 60)`;
client.geoadd(key, lon, lat, driverID);
```

but then querying becomes more complicated.

Comment: Is there any other method in redis that i can used to add/update and get date attribute on the basis of key? [Redis-api](https://cristian.regolo.cc/2015/07/07/introducing-the-geo-api-in-redis.html)

Comment: Really depends on what you want to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 0):

While `GEOADD` doesn't support this, you can store the date property in another key, e.g. something like this:

```
client.geoadd('drivers_locations', coordinates[0], coordinates[1], driverID);
client.hset('driver:' + id, 'date', ,ew Date().toString());
```